# Best way(s) to combine data on the same object

Tags: time-series, python

I have data of a solar *cell*'s performance. Each cell consists of 8 *pixels*, each of which have their own data for various metrics of performance (current, etc.) throughout time. I would like to combine these 8 time-current tables into one that is descriptive of the overall cell's performance. My problem is that the times at which measurements are taken vary slightly between the pixels, so I can't just average each row. What is the best way to approach this problem?